# Convert saved edits in pdf to latex code?

Tags: pdftex

I created a pdf using latex. After that I drew a diagram (mathematics diagram like a triangle) in pdf and saved the pdf. But the code relevant to the drawing is not in my latex code of the pdf. Is there a way to get that code.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: no ____________

Comment: But you can do drawings directly in latex, no need to do this in your pdf later on

Comment: Another possibility: save your edited pdf file with a different name and include your drawings as images in your tex file.